# Carrierwave uploading file - undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to upload a file in a form using carrierwave gem, but I get the following error:

NoMethodError in DashboardController#create : undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass

What am I doing wrong?

Request Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"bv+3HGSl2/sDUi/aXqDw+b3XWgBM+cvXUrAQTZxWHeA=",
 "song"=>{"user_id"=>"",
 "title"=>"2",
 "artist"=>"3",
 "album"=>"4",
 "musicfile"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000001bb5bb0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20131209-11818-jf368b>,
 @original_filename="dg.mp3",
 @content_type="audio/mp3",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"song[musicfile]\"; filename=\"dg.mp3\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/mp3\r\n">},
 "commit"=>"Upload"}
```

Controller methods:

```
  def new
        @song = Song.new
  end
  def create
        @song=Song.new(params[:song])
        @song.save
        uploader = MusicfileUploader.new
        uploader.store!(params[:song][:musicfile])

        #redirect_to dashboard_index_path
  end
```

Or if you need everything:

https://github.com/cristi92b/GS2

EDIT:

terminal server output:

```
Started GET "/dashboard/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-09 17:54:15 +0200
Processing by DashboardController#new as HTML
  Rendered dashboard/_form.html.erb (112.5ms)
  Rendered dashboard/new.html.erb within layouts/application (122.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 131ms (Views: 128.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

Started POST "/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-09 17:54:44 +0200
Processing by DashboardController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IfQNLZ8OuXjkowgj35C4BbC6nbusB+anhvNiL2SlEQY=", "song"=>{"user_id"=>"", "title"=>"1", "artist"=>"2", "album"=>"3", "musicfile"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003086080 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20131209-2805-1jvt87a>, @original_filename="dg.mp3", @content_type="audio/mp3", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"song[musicfile]\"; filename=\"dg.mp3\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/mp3\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Upload"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:12:in `create'


  Rendered /home/cristi/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /home/cristi/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /home/cristi/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /home/cristi/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (15.2ms)
```

web page "Full trace" :

```
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:35:in `write_attribute'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:70:in `write_attribute'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:21:in `__temp__57375627f59646='
activemodel (4.0.2) lib/active_model/model.rb:80:in `public_send'
activemodel (4.0.2) lib/active_model/model.rb:80:in `block in initialize'
activemodel (4.0.2) lib/active_model/model.rb:79:in `each'
activemodel (4.0.2) lib/active_model/model.rb:79:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:12:in `create'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__1534113615882314291__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__992470349095990657__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?

Comment: First line after def create, 'dashboard' controller

Comment: That was really the last line in the stacktrace?

Comment: Application trace: app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:12:in `create'

Comment: Is that perhaps the Rails error message output through the web? If so, is there a stack trace you can see on the Terminal window you're running the Rails server from?

Comment: Yes, the error message was on the web. I added full trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is due to `@attributes_cache` being `nil` inside of ActiveRecord. If you Google "@attributes_cache nil` you'll find a few questions about this but no answers. I realize this isn't much of an answer and will probably not really help you, but I thought this information belonged somewhere other than a comment. Hopefully, someone can build on it.

Comment: I solved the problem, it was because of an include inside the song model